# How I can add centered horizontal line behind the link using css?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to add centered horizontal line behind the link, so when I change size of the screen this line stays centered behind the link and moves with it. Also I need this line to be on the full width of screen.

On first image is what I have right now: [image]

On the second image is what I need, as yo can see there thin gray line centered behind "V" link:
[image]

My html code of this link:

```
<div class="welcome-content">
            <h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome To Kramerica Industries</h1>
            <div class="explore-container">
                <a class="v-explore-button" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <p class="explore-text">Explore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Sass:

```
 .welcome-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Droid Sans Bold", "sans-serif";
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .explore-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 147%;
    left: 38%;



    .v-explore-button {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #2ecc71;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }

    .explore-text {
      margin-top: 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `position: absolute` on `.explore-container`? It looks awkward to maintain.

Comment: Wrap the anchor tag of the v button with a <hr> inside a div container. Vertically align the child containers, that is the <a> and <hr> in the middle.

Comment: I need to have this container to be on the bottom center of the section relative to different screen sizes, it's only way how I know to do this. `text-align:center` not working for me, because this container stands right under `h1` and I need to have it on the bottom center. I can't use `hr`, need to do this with css.

Comment: @Belial Did you even check the snippet I posted and tried to use it?

Comment: yes I checked, it works, but not on the full width of the screen, It have full width only on the right side of the button.

Comment: My code works fine, and it only shows on the right side of the button is because you didn't remove what I mentioned as my second point in the answer. Remove the left:38% on your explore container, set its width to 100% and use text-align:center like I did with it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

.welcome-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Droid Sans Bold", "sans-serif";
  color: #ffffff;
}

.explore-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.v-explore-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.explore-text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.explore-container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: .15em;
  background-color: #00bade;
}

.inner-wrap{
  margin-right: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-content">
  <h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome To Kramerica Industries</h1>
  <div class="explore-container">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <a class="v-explore-button" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-
      down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <p class="explore-text">Explore</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My recommendation would be to use a pseudo-element such as before:
See example for the solution. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the translate property to align elements inside a
  container in the middle as demonstrated below without needing to
  calculate the approximate % value to align it.
- Instead of giving left:`38%` to your `explore-container`, set its width to 100% and align the elements using `text-align:center` as shown below.

I hope this helps.

```css
.welcome-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Droid Sans Bold", "sans-serif";
}

.explore-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 147%;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  }
  
  .v-explore{
    position:relative;
    background:yellow;
  }
  
  .v-explore-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  
  .explore-text {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="welcome-content">
  <h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome To Kramerica Industries</h1>
  <div class="explore-container">
    <div class="v-explore">
    <a class="v-explore-button" href="#about">v</a>
    <hr>
    </div>
    <p class="explore-text">Explore</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to use ::before inline block pseudoelement for button class  in pair with transform:translateY(50% of the button width);and 100% width?

Comment: do you have example so I can see what exactly you mean?